# Can "a" be used to mean "about"?

Tags: word-usage

In [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179188/140449), I read the following sentence. (The post is visible to Meta Stack Overflow 10K users and moderators.)

> You've also got a 16 users ignoring you and still manage to consistently get enough 10k users to flag you.

I remember I have seen a similar sentence where *a* was used as in "a twenty cars."

Can *a* be used to mean *about*?

Comment: I don't remember the sentence, but it was about something involving cars (e.g. a crash). Take "The crash involved a twenty cars." as example, but I don't really remember that sentence to say "it was exactly like that."

Comment: "a" here could be either an undeleted letter from "about", which was deleted because the writer discovered that there were, in fact, **exactly** 20 cars, or a typo that should have "ca.", which means "about". That abbreviation isn't normally used in newspaper articles, though, unless it's in parentheses: "(ca. 20 cars)".

Comment: @snailboat: I don't know it, I'm sorry to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a typo.  It's definitely not standard, and I think it's ungrammatical.

The article ***a*** can't directly modify ***16 users***, so ***a 16 users*** must be part of a larger noun phrase.  This means that ***16 users*** must be a noun adjunct for a following head noun.  However, the only choices for head are ***ignoring*** and ***you***, and neither works very well.  So, as far as I can tell, there's no way to make this sentence work in standard English.

I don't think it means "about", but the only way to be sure what they intended is to ask them.

Comment: Do you mean a phrase like "a 16 users group" and "a twenty cars crash"?

Comment: I do mean *like* those, but in both of those cases they would be singular: "a 16 user group" and "a twenty car crash".  I'm struggling to think of a grammatical example where the word in that position is plural.  I think it might only work if the adjunct is taken as a proper noun, like "I stayed at a Four Seasons hotel", in which case it's not really plural.

Comment: I found some discussion on Wikipedia when I searched for plural noun adjuncts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#English